# My parallax scrolling did not move smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollmagic

[image]

Hello there. I made a parallax scrolling with [ScrollMagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic). But it has little issue like this GIF image. When scrolling, the images are scrolled but move up and down little repeatedly in the same time. This issue can be found in Safari, Firefox, Chrome on OS X 10.11 Did I code wrong source? Please confirm the source. Thanks a lot read it. Have a nice code:>

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="skrollr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 15500px">
        <img id="logo" src="logo.png"></img>
        <img id="logo-fix" src="logo.png" style="position: fixed; right: 5px;"</img>
        <h2 id="pt1" style="position: absolute">ParallaxTest 1</h2><br><br>
        <h2 id="pt2" style="position: absolute">ParallaxTest 2</h2>


<!-- Parallax scroll code start -->
        <section id="trigger2">
            <div id="pxPt" style="position: relative">
                <!-- You'll be not able to see loose1.png in GIF, cause did not recored. -->
                <img id="pt1" style="position: absolute" src="loose1.png"></img>
                <img id="pt2" style="position: absolute" src="loose2.png"></img>
                <img id="pt3" style="position: absolute" src="loose3.png"></img>
            </div>
        </section>
<!-- Parallax scroll code end -->

    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(function () { // wait for document ready
        var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
        // build scene
        var logoScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            pushFollowers: false,
            duration: 0,  // the scene should last for a scroll distance of 100px
            offset: 0      // start this scene after scrolling for 50px
        })
        .setPin("#logo") // pins the element for the the scene's duration
        .addTo(controller);


// Parallax scroll code start
        var tween = new TimelineMax()
        .add([
            TweenMax.fromTo("#pxPt #pt1", 1, {scale: 1, autoAlpha: 0.05, top: 150}, {top: 15250, ease: Linear.easeNone}),
            TweenMax.fromTo("#pxPt #pt2", 1, {scale: 1, autoAlpha: 0.42, top: 50}, {top: 15350, ease: Linear.easeNone}),
            TweenMax.fromTo("#pxPt #pt3", 1, {scale: 1, autoAlpha: 0.42, top: 75}, {top: 15500, ease: Linear.easeNone})
        ]);

        var parallaxScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: "#trigger2",
            duration: 15500
        })
        .setTween(tween)
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
// Parallax scroll code end

    });
</script>
```